# poll exiting immidiately from driver

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

This is my first experience of implementing a driver in linux kernel & facing this problem.

I am trying to implement "poll()" in my character driver. 
  I have called poll_wait() & passed a wait queue.

When the device file of this driver is opened from the user space program & called "poll" system call on this device file descriptor (fd), poll system call exits immediately even when there is no data to be send to the user space.

It does not wait for even timeout period.

I am unable to figure out what is causing this problem.

Can anyone suggest any solution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When someone calls `poll()` system call on device file then vfs layer handles it this way.

It calls your driver's poll handler (henceforth referred as my_poll).

1. If you do not call poll_wait then upper layer will just return mask without analyzing its value.
2. If you add your driver/calling process to a wait queue using `poll_wait()` then calling process will be added to wait queue.

Do not get deceived by the API's name `poll_wait()`. It doesn't actually wait or sleeps. It merely adds your process to the list of waiting processes for receiving event notification.

After returning from `poll_wait()`, the entire behavior depends on the mask returned. Value of this mask is used by VFS layer. If the mask returned is zero, it'll put the calling process to sleep. Now the process is waiting for the event to happen.

When someone awakens this wait queue, all waiting processes gets notification. VFS layer again calls `my_poll()` & checks returned value of mask.

Above process continues until VFS layer  receives a non-zero mask.
It means my_poll() will be called multiple times. So anyone who wants to implement poll/read in his device driver, should check whether device is actually ready for read/write operation before returning readiness mask.
Important thing to note here is that do not assume that `poll_wait()` will sleep until someone awakens that queue.

Comment: If `my_poll()` can be called multiple times, that means so does `poll_wait()`. Wouldn't multiple `poll_wait()` invocations mean that the same process is added to the list of waiting processes multiple times? Isn't that bad because now we have duplicated entries in the list?

Comment: Or maybe `poll_wait` is smart enough to _not_ add the same process more than once to the list?